# I want to change an object attribute value in an api request but it is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, axios

I am doing api calls with axios on express. I have an external API controller that has different functions to call and fetch data from the IGDB api.

I have a gameController.js that will build a finalized JSON object using the different data fetched from the different calls.

this is my **gameController.js**

```
const externalApiController = require("./externalApiController");

exports.getGames = async (req, res) => {
  var initialGameResult = await externalApiController.getGames(
    req.body.searchInput
  );
  await initialGameResult.forEach(async (game) => {
    if (game.cover) {
      const cover = await externalApiController.getCover(game.cover);
      console.log(cover[0]);
      // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      game.cover = cover[0]; // MY ISSUE IS HERE. IT IS NOT CHANGING
      // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    }
  });
  res.send(initialGameResult); //SEND THE UNCHANGED DATA
};
```

This is my **externalApiController.js**

```
var axios = require("axios");
require("dotenv").config();

exports.getGames = async (searchInput) => {
  var data = `fields id,name,cover,platforms,category,genres,collection ; search "${searchInput}"; limit 5;`;
  var config = {
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.igdb.com/v4/games",
    headers: {
      "Client-ID": process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    },
    data: data,
  };
  const result = await axios(config);

  //   console.log(result.data);
  return result.data;
};

exports.getCover = async (id) => {
  var data = `fields id, url; where id = ${id};`;
  var config = {
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.igdb.com/v4/covers",
    headers: {
      "Client-ID": process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    },
    data: data,
  };

  const result = await axios(config);

  //   console.log(result.data);
  return result.data;
};
```

Basically [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ4By.png) is the data that I get from the initial request.
It is correct. But as seen in the picture, the cover is an ID value. I need to fetch another API request using that value to get the image URL. It works fine in the **foreach** line. When i log it i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmQ6k.png).

However, it does not change in this line: **game.cover = cover[0];**

I need the data to change from:

```
{
   "id": 110248,
   "category": 0,
   "cover": 225254,
   "genres": [
      31,
      32
   ],
   "name": "Stray",
   "platforms": [
      6,
      48,
      167
   ]
},
```

to:

```
{
   "id": 110248,
   "category": 0,
   "cover": {
      id: whatever_id_it_is,
      url: whatever_url_it_is
   },
   "genres": [
      31,
      32
   ],
   "name": "Stray",
   "platforms": [
      6,
      48,
      167
   ]
},
```

Also, I am not quite sure I am using the **async** and **await** correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `.forEach(async (game)` part. When you await result of `.forEach`, it will not wait for all promises to finish executing. `.forEach` returns `void` so it merely iterates over array elements and sends the promises to event loop.

The trick is to change `.forEach` to `.map` and pipe that to `Promise.all` to ensure your promises finish executing.

Change from:

```js
const externalApiController = require("./externalApiController");
exports.getGames = async (req, res) => {
  var initialGameResult = await externalApiController.getGames(req.body.searchInput);
  await initialGameResult.forEach(async (game) => {
    if (game.cover) {
      const cover = await externalApiController.getCover(game.cover);
      console.log(cover[0]);
      // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      game.cover = cover[0];
      // MY ISSUE IS HERE. IT IS NOT CHANGING
      // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    }
  });
  res.send(initialGameResult); // SEND THE UNCHANGED DATA
};
```

To:

```js
const externalApiController = require("./externalApiController");
exports.getGames = async (req, res) => {
  var initialGameResult = await externalApiController.getGames(req.body.searchInput);
  const modifiedGameResult = await Promise.all(initialGameResult.map(async (game) => {
    if (game.cover) {
      const cover = await externalApiController.getCover(game.cover);
      console.log(cover[0]);
      game.cover = cover[0];
    }
    return game;
  }));
  res.send(modifiedGameResult);
};
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you  a lot! It was a bit slow though in execution. Any tips or advice on how i can optimize it ?

Comment: @QoussayElAkkari Optimizing is a topic for another StackOverflow question ;) In short - you can try caching the  requests to `externalApiController.getCover`  w/ smth like https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-memoize

Don't forget to accept this answer if it solves your problem!

Comment: Already accepted it. And thank you for your advice.

I want to now change the platforms in the object i am sending. I tried using the same logic you used for the cover but in vain. It returns an empty array even though it is been logged correctly. Is there a way i can send you the code ? It is a few lines and I would really appreciate the help

Comment: @QoussayElAkkari it's better you create a new stackoverflow question for the next problem. You can send me a link to it here in the comments